# CSS: Expanding the Hover

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I Have a menu bar down the side of my website and i would like the hover to span the width of the menu bar, so far its only covering the text.

I want it to look like this, and have them all end where the menu ends

[image: Image 1]

but instead it looks like this

[image: Image 2]

HTML:

```css
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
        border-radius: 0px;
        max-width: 96vw;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw 0.5vw 0.8vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
    
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

I'm new to HTML and CSS so any help or advice is very much appriciated :)

Comment: Add your HTML to question.

Comment: You broke the image links with that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `display: block;` to `#menu a`

```css
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
        border-radius: 0px;
        max-width: 96vw;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw 0.5vw 0.8vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
    display: block;
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` elements are inline elements, which side with their content, that's why the white area is only as wide as the text.

To solve that, display the links as a block:

```
#menu a { display: block; }
```

Block elements, by default, fill the available width inside their parents.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
display: block;
```

to your `#menu` a selector. If this doesn't work, please provide the HTML of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the hover pseudo class to li element instead of a element. Check below code. This way you highlighted background will take effect to the size of the li.

```css
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
        border-radius: 0px;
        max-width: 96vw;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.8vw 0.5vw 0.8vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
    
}
#menu li:hover {
    
    background-color: #FFFFFF;}

#menu li:hover a {
    
    color: #000;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```